# Spring Security REST - Invalidate Refresh Token when accountExpired

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have an application that uses Grails 3.1, Spring Security, and Spring Security REST.

In my User entity, I have the accountExpired field, which, when set to true, prevents the user from accessing the web system.

However, in the mobile application, I obtain an access token and a refresh token that never expire. In other words, the user logs in once and remains logged in until they perform a logout.

Since accountExpired doesn't invalidate the refresh token, I need a way to invalidate the user's access in the mobile application.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: by keeping state server side of all refresh tokens that have been issued, and on each call look in your "database" if the refreshtoken has been revoked or not.

Comment: You may add a user update hook of gorm and in that hook, invalidate the refresh token?  if you would like to go this direction,  I can offer some sample code how to do this.

Comment: @LawrenceLiu Yes you can show this sample code please

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Grails interceptors, which will intercept all calls, and give you the chance to kick them out...

https://grails.org/blog/2015-03-01.html

If that's not good enough, You might have to write a security servlet filter and inherit from AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. That's a lot more tricky, though very doable if you need it.